# AJAX requests in mobile widgets

Tags: javascript, widget, mobile-phones, w3c

I've added the code for an AJAX call in my mobile widget but I don't get a response. Any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/disruptions-tube-offset-now.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your config.xml contains the security tag and network="public" attribute inside widget tag:

```
<security>
  <access>
    <host>tfl.gov.uk</host>
  </access>
</security>
```

Answer (score 1):

The response is inside the success function

```
success: function(xml) {}
```

Unless there is a failure.